# How to import local classes when using setuptools

Tags: python

So my file system looks something like this

```
/projects
--setup.py
--setup.cfg
--/app
--/--__init__.py
--/--app.py
--/--file_with_class.py
```

In my app.py I import file_with_class.py, but when I use setup to install my module with pip install . and try running it, I get this error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'className'

supose file_with_class.py contains a class named className

I'm importing this class in app.py like this:

```
from file_with_class import className
```

Also, when executing app.py on its own it works perfectly, the problem comes when creating the package with setuptools and after installing my own package, trying to run it.

Comment: how are you importing class.py in app.py ?

Comment: Not sure how this is related to setuptools. You need to use relative imports: `from . import cls` (as a separate issue, you can't have a module named `class`)

Comment: I'm naming it class here just as an example meaning it contains a class, also I'm just importing it as `from class import class`

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative import:

```
from . import class
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use either relative, or fully qualified module name imports:

```py
from . import class

# or, probably better:
import app.class
from app import class
```

BTW, `class` is a reserved word. Not sure if this was the module's name in your original code, but if it was you probably want to avoid it.